# ListView dentro de ListView (ANDROID)

Tags: android, android-studio, listview

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação onde esta possui uma activity onde gera uma ListView de Pedidos, e dentro do Adapter desta lista de pedidos, eu tenho outra ListView que são os itens, ou seja, eu tenho uma ListView dentro de outra ListView.

O problema é que o Android não deixa colocar uma ListView dentro de uma View que possua ScrollView, e por padrão, uma ListView já tem Scroll.

Para resolver isso, eu encontrei em fóruns na internet um código que percorreria os itens da minha list filha, pegar o tamanho de cada linha e assim, somando um tamanho total, porém ele não funcionou muito certo no meu projeto, alguém teria uma outra solução para isso? obrigado.

Código que encontrei na internet:

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
if (listAdapter == null)
    return;

int desiredWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
int totalHeight = 0;
View view = null;
for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
    view = listAdapter.getView(i, view, listView);
    if (i == 0)
        view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(desiredWidth, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    view.measure(desiredWidth, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    totalHeight += view.getMeasuredHeight();
}
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
listView.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

**O que está acontecendo:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que está acontecendo com esse código que você utilizou? Poderia mandar um print do que está acontecendo?

Comment: `listView.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false`

Comment: @BonecoSinforoso http://uploaddeimagens.com.br/images/002/142/423/full/print_erro.png?1560552933

Comment: @EduardoDornel não resolveu

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema com o código a baixo!

```
public void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null) {
        // pre-condition
        return;
    }

    int totalHeight = listView.getPaddingTop() + listView.getPaddingBottom();
    int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);

        if(listItem != null){
            // This next line is needed before you call measure or else you won't get measured height at all. The listitem needs to be drawn first to know the height.
            listItem.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            listItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();

        }
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
}
```